# My model messes up after importing to unity from blender

Tags: modeling, texturing, import, unity

I have created a cliff model in blender and it is my first ever model. I have tried a lot to fix this but I can't get what must be done.

this is my model...[image: top isometric view]

[image: bottom view]

this is how it looks after rendering...

[image: rendered image]

this is how it looks in viewport shading window...[image]

this is how it looks in unity...[image: unity]

I am new to all this modelling and blender, Guys please help me sort out this problem.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Hi. The 'blender-internal-render-engine' tag relates to the Blender Internal render engine (present in blender 2.79). Is this the render engine you are using?

Comment: Yes, I am using blender 2.8